# Exclusive and shared locks in bash

Tags: bash, unix, flock

I am trying to lock a file using bash, and I have managed to do so, but I am not sure if I am doing it the right way.

The following piece of code should try to write into the `lock.log` file and if it fails it should exit with exit status -1. If it can lock the file, then it should print the order number, unlock the file, and exit.

```
#!/bin/bash

function myfunc {
    (
        flock -e -n 200 || { echo "$1 - can't reach"; exit -1; }
        echo $1 >> $2 #critical
        sleep 2
        flock -u 200
    ) 200>$2 #critical
    echo "$1 -> end."
    exit 0
}

lock="lock.log"
for ((i=0; i < 10; i++)); do
    myfunc $i $lock &
done

exit 0
```

I could not understand why it would print on the standard output and the 2 lines that are tagged as critical are not quite clear to me, so I kindly ask for some explanation and maybe for a better example.

There may be some similar questions, but none with the basic things that I am asking - the usage of `flock`

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the `200>"$2"` part:

When `myfunc` is called Bash sees this:

```
(
    ... stuff irrelevant for now ...
) 200>"$2"
```

so it opens file descriptor number 200 and will redirect it to the file obtained by expansion of `$2`. In your case, it's exactly like:

```
(
    ... stuff irrelevant for now ...
) 200>lock.log
```

By the way, file `lock.log` is at this point opened and truncated (i.e., its content, if any, is cleared).

To see this, try the following:

```
( ls /dev/fd ) 200>lock.log
```

You'll see that there's a “file” called `200` in there (at this point, try it with a `lock.log` file that has some content, and you'll see that after that its content disappeared) but compare with

```
ls /dev/fd
```

where you very likely only see `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`. For fun, try:

```
( ls /dev/fd >&200 ) 200>lock.log
```

This time nothing is shown on your terminal screen, but you'll see that the content of `ls` is in the file `lock.log` (with its previous content, if any, deleted). That's because with `>&200` we redirected the standard output of `ls` to the file descriptor `200` which is `/dev/fd/200`, and this is then redirected to the file `lock.log`.

I guess this explains one of the *critical* lines.

Now what happens inside the subshell? I'm no `flock` expert, so bear with me.

With the argument `200`, you're telling `flock` to use the file descriptor `200` (i.e., the “file” `/dev/fd/200`) as a lock file. When you call `flock 200`, `flock` tries to get a hold on the file. If it can, all is good, it keeps the grasp on it, otherwise it either fails (if given the `-n` option, which is your case) or it waits until someone else let the file go.

In case of failure, you're outputting the *can't reach* message *to standard output* and exit the subshell, and then you're executing the remaining part of the function (namely, the message *end*). Now, in case of success you're `echo`ing the first argument passed to the function (here a number) and you're redirecting it to file `lock.log`. Does that explain the second *critical* line?

At the end of this script, you'll see that the file `lock.log` is empty. That's because the first call to myfunc succeeds, but all subsequent calls will truncate the file `lock.log` (rings a bell with you?). If you want to see some content inside `lock.log`, either call your function only once (so that no subsequent calls truncate the file), or open the file in append mode:

```
(
    ... the flock stuff ...
) 200>>"$2" # notice the >> instead of >
```

Like so you'll see the first lock that succeeded (not necessarily the number `0`, as there are race conditions).

Comment: thank you a lot for the thorough answer! It did explain to me a lot of things about the file locking.
Also, can you please tell me how do processes notify when one has finished writing into a file? Exclusive to shared locks, and how do I know what part of the file content has been added? (assuming we append at the end)

Comment: @Mark I don't really understand your questions. `flock` uses the system call `flock()`—see `man 2 flock`— to apply a lock on the file. I have no idea what the kernel really does when such a call is performed—but at our level it is irrelevant. There are no notifications (at this level, as far as I can tell) when a process has finished writing into a file (unless, of course, blocking locks are queried, but this is not your case since you're using the `-n` switch). All this is done at the kernel level and isn't really our concern at our level.

Comment: @Mark I guess it would be better to tell exactly what you're trying to do (either by editing the question if this can be done in a very concise way), or by asking a new question (that will reference this one) if your task is more involved.